# How to reload the script present inside head tag of index.html in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am searching so many solutions but I am unable to find one.

I have written some script inside the `head` tag (above `</body>` also I tried) in `index.html`. I have written `$(document).ready` function inside it.

When the server starts that time the script will work. But until refreshing the page, the script will not work, when I come back from a different component to the component where the script is used.

So my question is how can I refresh the `index.html`?.
If I do so, the whole application gets refreshed. How to prevent it?
Is there any different way to reuse my script code again and again it?
Please provide me with a solution.

I tried importing an external `js` file in `index.html`. That time function will not be invoked.
I tried writing `js` code inside `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. That also did not work.

Comment: According to me you can also load the script file use service you can write a same code for load script file in service on same event and you can trigger when you want

Comment: Refreshing pages will nullify the use of SPA like angular. May be you should change your logic, like moving it to a service.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are aware how $(document).ready works. It will be called once your document is ready which happen when you load/refresh/reload your page.

Now the question arises, what exactly the script is doing? If it's something which setting some global scopes then, you should abstract out the **logic in a service** and, call it in each component you want to use. Make sure you are initialization/calling your script/logic before your component loads.

```
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

  myData() {
    return 'This is my data!';
  }

}

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.myData();
  }

}
```

Or, if it is something which is keeping running behind the scene just like an background thread, then you can use **setInterval api** in your AppComponent/ContainerComponent which will keep running behind the scene. This way your script will always be in context.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.id = setInterval(() => {
    this.Init(); 
  }, 1000);
}
```

I would suggest you to share your about your problem statement, it will be easier for people to provide proper solution.